How do I remove an underscore from the name of a file?
I'm doing a cleaning of a runtime directory (checking which files are not needed and delete them).
I thought doing this the "smart" way, renaming bunches of files by adding an underscore at the beginning of the file. Like this, the file is not usable anymore, but as it is still present, all I need to do is to remove the underscore and I can use the file again.
While doing this file by file, it's working like a charm.
... but I've just rename a whole bunch of files, called Telerik.Windows.*.dll into _telerik.Windows.*.dll, but how can I do that?
Hereby my command for adding an underscore:
forfiles /M Telerik.Windows.*.dll /c "cmd /c rename @file _@file"

How can I get rid of that underscore again? (Is there a forfiles way?)
I have just tried the following, but it failed:
forfiles /M _Telerik.Windows.*.dll /c "cmd /c rename @file @file:~1"

Reason for the failure:
forfiles /M _Telerik.Windows.*.dll /c "cmd /c echo @file:~1"
"_Telerik.Windows.Analytics.dll":~1
"_Telerik.Windows.Controls.Chart.dll":~1
"_Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.dll":~1
"_Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataServices.dll":~1
...

I do believe that the ~1 trick (for removing the first character) is the solution, but how can I correctly implement it?
